# ajax php file upload and php page failed to retrieve the file

Tags: php, ajax

HTML:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    Upload image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#photoimg').change(function() {
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

    var data = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#photoimg')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file-' + i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaximage.php',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {}
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Need help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code posted is not a valid Javascript or PHP. Looks like you have just taken parts of code and mashed them together. If this is how it actually looks of course it won't work. `<?php ?>` and `<script></script` should be used for starters.

Comment: Are you trying to upload file with $.ajax ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload files via `AJAX`. You can use this ajax **[form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)**

#### **[`Example`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload)**

Comment: $('#photoimg').change( function()
{$("#preview").html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
var oOutput = document.getElementById("preview");
 var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("imageform"));
 
  oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "ajaximage.php", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      oOutput.innerHTML =  oReq.responseText ;
    } else {
      oOutput.innerHTML = "Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
    }
};oReq.send(oData);});